# Check_box_tag in rails persist through page load

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-3, search, checkbox

I have a Rails 3.2.20 app where I'm stacking several search queries/scopes together which come across as params in a view.

I have everything working so when I make my selections in the select_tag the will persist on page reload using something like this:

```
<%= select_tag "search[attendant]", options_from_collection_for_select(Medic.order(:medic_name), :medic_name, :medic_name, selected: params[:search].try(:[], :attendant)), prompt: "Select Attendant" %>
```

I'm trying to do another search criteria using the `check_box_tag` like so:

```
<%= check_box_tag "search[unbilled]", selected: params[:search].try(:[], :unbilled) %>
```

This works when I check the box and it will pass the search param key of `unbilled` to the model and scope out the records I want properly.  The problem is when I click a different page through pagination or reload the page after hitting submit/search the checkbox will not persist.

I'm pretty sure my syntax for the `check_box_tag` is incorrect.  I'd like to figure out how to use `selected` in the `check_box_tag` similar to how I do it in the `select_tag` from my previous example to persist the checkbox tick.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Why you are using `params[:search].try(:[], :unbilled)`. it will return nil if `:[]` is not return value.

Use `params[:search].try(:unbilled)` if unbilled method available on parms[:search] otherwise use some other way to pass value to selected attribute.

Comment: Actually that was a blunder.  And using `.try(:unbilled)` results in a no method error.  Do you have a more appropriate answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the params to set the value

`value="#{params[:checkbox]}"` // just an example

The first time the page will render it will be false by default, and second time you reload the form, it should fill the value with params.